# Creating a new column and assigning it a value, based on an if condition

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, dataframe, assignment-operator

I have a dataframe:
[image]

I want to iterate through it to check if it is a word in an NLTK supported reference. Within the if statement, I want to create a new column called 'bool' and assign a true or false depending on it the reference is good or not. I wrote the following code, and for some reason it returns all falses even though it ought to be a mix. Here is the code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

for each in df['word']:
    if not wordnet.synsets(each):
        df['new'] = False
        print('Not an English Word')       
    else:
        df['new'] = True
        print('English Word')  

df
```

The outputs are:
[image]

and:
[image]

The first output is fine. However, the second output should have a "True" in every other row in the column 'bool' like this:
[image]

I dont' understand why my code is not able to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this took a while, but here it is:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

real_wds = []

for each in df['word']:
    if not wordnet.synsets(each):
        real_wds.append(False)
    else:
        real_wds.append(True)
df['bool'] = real_wds

df
```

and the output is:
[image]

Essentially, I needed to create an empty list outside the loop, then append the test results through each iteration. Then when the loop is finished, I set the new column equal to the contents of the populated list.